# SQL Joining / merging two event tables, sensitive to corresponding time

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, merge, union

Table 1 has open times.

```
id |  OpenTime
1  | 2019-12-02 16:52:42.9130000
1  | 2019-12-02 16:55:57.5560000
1  | NULL
1  | 2019-12-02 16:59:09.5640000
1  | 2019-12-02 17:01:35.3510000
2  | 2019-12-02 17:02:55.0270000
2  | 2019-12-02 17:05:41.3930000
2  | 2019-12-02 17:07:41.7870000
```

Table 2 has close times.

```
id |  CloseTime
1  | NULL
1  | 2019-12-02 16:56:19.2560000
1  | 2019-12-02 16:57:47.5790000
1  | 2019-12-02 16:59:33.5390000
1  | 2019-12-02 17:01:55.6040000
2  | 2019-12-02 17:04:00.7780000
2  | 2019-12-02 17:06:04.4830000
```

I need to do a `DATEDIFF` calculation for each open to close time.

It can only be open once at a time, however, we can be missing that event.

We may not yet have the close event.

An OpenTime will normally have a corresponding CloseTime, with CloseTime being greater than OpenTime, but less than the next OpenTime.

```
id |  OpenTime                    | CloseTime                    | Datedif
1  | 2019-12-02 16:52:42.9130000  | NULL                         | NULL
1  | 2019-12-02 16:55:57.5560000  | 2019-12-02 16:56:19.2560000  | 
1  | NULL                         | 2019-12-02 16:57:47.5790000  | NULL
1  | 2019-12-02 16:59:09.5640000  | 2019-12-02 16:59:33.5390000  | 
1  | 2019-12-02 17:01:35.3510000  | 2019-12-02 17:01:55.6040000  | 
2  | 2019-12-02 17:02:55.0270000  | 2019-12-02 17:04:00.7780000  | 
2  | 2019-12-02 17:05:41.3930000  | 2019-12-02 17:06:04.4830000  | 
2  | 2019-12-02 17:07:41.7870000  | NULL                         | NULL
```

Datediff will just be in seconds `DATEDIFF(SECOND,OpenTime,CloseTime)`.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #NEWTABLE;
SELECT 
  a.ID,
  MAX(a.OpenTime) as OpenTime,
  MIN(b.CloseTime) as CloseTime ,
  DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.OpenTime, b.CloseTime) AS diffSeconds
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM Table1  a
JOIN Table2 b
  ON a.Id= b.Id
WHERE 
a.Id = b.ID
and b.CloseTime> = a.OpenTime

Group by a.Id,DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.OpenTime, b.CloseTime)
order by diffSeconds desc
```

This is not working, but I've tried to make sure that I get the correct corresponding CloseTime to each OpenTime. My code gives 26 rows output for 8 Open and Close events.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `LEAD` to find the next open time and get the respective record from table2

```
with cte as(
select id, opentime, lead(opentime,1) over (order by opentime) nextopentime
from table1
where opentime is not null)
select a.id, a.opentime, b.closetime
from cte a 
    left join table2 b on a.id = b.id and b.closetime > a.opentime and b.closetime < a.nextopentime
order by a.opentime
```

Comment: You should avoid using BETWEEN. [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: @ChrisAlbert, thanks for the information. have changed the logic with `<` and `>`